# Why add String (), if without it work?

Tags: javascript, html

Please, help me, guys

```
var main_html = String()
            + '<div class="spa-shell-head">'
            + '<div class="spa-shell-head-logo"></div>'
            + '</div>'
```

same thing:

```
var main_html = '<div class="spa-shell-head">'
              + '<div class="spa-shell-head-logo"></div>'
              + '</div>'
```

what is the difference?

p.s. Sorry for my english. Thank you

Comment: `String()` creates the empty string `""` so it's completely useless here and, in a context where you want the empty string, you'd use the litteral `""` anyway.

Comment: There is no difference, `String()` returns an empty string, which is totally unnecessary here. I guess the thing is, why are you even considering it?

Comment: I saw these examples in tutorial and in commercial projects

Answer (score 1):

first of all it looks like you just need to use equal sign instead of colon.

`var main_html = String()
    + '<div class="spa-shell-head">'
    + '<div class="spa-shell-head-logo"></div>'
    + '</div>';`

Putting `String()` (or just empty string like `''`) in the beginning of an addition expression will give us resulting string. Sort of type coercion in JS.
E.g. 
`String() + 5 --> '5'`, 
`String() + true --> 'true'`, etc.
With it you can be sure that `main_html` variable is string, not number or boolean.

Actually in your case it is not obligatory to write it in that way. Since you're adding string to string you'll always get string. 
So the second code example works completely the same as the first one.

Comment: Thats not the question though (although I agree with you, or remove the `var` if its part of the object)

Comment: Aw, yep, you're right. Let me just correct my answer.

Comment: Thanks, i resolve mistake in code. I know coercion of types. So, I  confused by this code.